# Compiler Programs .. i have some error in it

Tags: java, compiler-construction

where is my Error in this project ?
[here is my source code](http://www.4shared.com/file/O_ovBMHN/First_Project.html)

> Compiler program

- after i run this code which i create it .. it gives me these errors :
- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
- at First_Project.First_Project.LetsDoThis(First_Project.java:78)
- at First_Project.First_Project.main(First_Project.java:27)
- so ,  what is my error and where ?

> package First_Project;
>
> ```
>   import java.io.File;
>   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
>   import java.io.PrintWriter;
>   import java.util.Scanner;
>
>  public class First_Project {
>
>  private static PrintWriter output;
>  private static Scanner input;
>  static char LF;
>
>  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
>
>     File inputFile = new File("D:\\input.txt");
>     if (!inputFile.exists()) {
>         System.out.println("Input file, " + inputFile + ", does not exist.");
>         System.exit(0);
>     }
>
>     // Output File:
>     File outputFile = new File("D:\\outputbaraa.txt");
>     output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
>     // Make Scanner for input and Printwriter for output
>     LetsDoThis();
>
>
>
>
>
> }
> static String Text = ""; // string to store lexemes
> static String WORD[] = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char",
>     "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "for", "final",
>     "finally", "float", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native",
>     "new", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "strictfp*", "super", "switch",
>     "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"};
>
> public static void error() {
>     output.println(Text + "\t\tUnknown Character\n");
>     Text = "";
>     output.flush();
> }
>
> private static boolean isLetter(char c) {
>     return (((int) c > 96 && (int) c < 123)
>             || ((int) c > 64 && (int) c < 91));
> }
>
> private static boolean isDigit(char c) {
>     return ((int) c > 47 && (int) c < 58);
> }
>
> private static boolean isReservedWord(String word) {
>     for (int i = 0; i < WORD.length; i++) {
>         if (word.equals(WORD[i])) {
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
>     return false;
> }
>
> private static boolean isWhiteSpace(char lookahead) {
>     return (lookahead == '\r' || lookahead == '\t' || lookahead == ' '
>             || lookahead == '\n' || lookahead == '\r');
> }
>
> public static void LetsDoThis() {
>
>
>     output.println("Lexemes\t\tTokens\n");
>     output.flush();
>
>     String line;
>     String text = "";
>     while (input.hasNext()) {
>         line = input.nextLine();
>         text += line;
>     }
>     // <, >, <=, >=, ==
>     // <,<=, >
>     int state = 0;
>     int position = 0; // index for text
>     int flag = 0;
>     LF = text.charAt(position++);
>     // while not end of inputfile
>     //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="While code ^_^">
>     while (position < text.length() - 3
>             && !"\000".equals(text.substring(text.length() - 3, text.length()))) {
>         switch (state) {
>             case 0:
>                 if (isWhiteSpace(LF)) {
>                     state = 0;
>                     LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 } else {
>
>                     // append character to Text variable
>                     Text += LF;
>
>                     if (LF == '_' || isLetter(LF)) {
>                         state = 1;
>                     } else if (isDigit(LF)) {
>                         state = 3;
>                     } else if (LF == ',') {
>                         state = 5;
>                     } else if (LF == ';') {
>                         state = 6;
>                     } else if (LF == ':') {
>                         state = 7;
>                     } else if (LF == '?') {
>                         state = 8;
>                     } else if (LF == '{') {
>                         state = 9;
>                     } else if (LF == '}') {
>                         state = 10;
>                     } else if (LF == '(') {
>                         state = 11;
>                     } else if (LF == ')') {
>                         state = 12;
>                     } else if (LF == '=') {
>                         state = 13;
>                         LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                         if (LF == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '+') {
>                         LF = text.charAt(position);
>                         // if a single '+' operator
>                         state = 14;
>                         // if it is a double '+' operator    
>                         if (LF == '+') {
>                             state = 19;
>                             // if '=' operator    
>                         } else if (LF == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '-') {
>                         state = 15;
>                         LF = text.charAt(position);
>                         if (LF == '-') {
>                             state = 20;
>                         } else if (LF == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '*') {
>                         state = 16;
>                         if (text.charAt(position) == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '/') {
>                         state = 17;
>                         if (text.charAt(position) == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '%') {
>                         state = 18;
>                         if (text.charAt(position) == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '<') {
>                         state = 21;
>                         if (text.charAt(position) == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                             Text += text.charAt(position++);
>                         }
>                     } else if (LF == '>') {
>                         state = 22;
>                         if (text.charAt(position) == '=') {
>                             flag = 1;
>                         }
>                     } else {
>                         error();
>                         LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                         state = 0;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 //</editor-fold>
>                 break;
>             case 1:
>
>                 //Read the next character from the input inputfile
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>
>                 // if (_, Letter, Digit) remain at the same state
>                 if (LF == '_' || isLetter(LF) || isDigit(LF)) {
>                     Text += String.valueOf(LF);
>                 } else {
>                     state = 2;
>                 }
>                 break;
>             case 2:
>                 state = 0;
>                 if (isReservedWord(Text)) {
>                     output.println(Text + "\t\t" + Text);
>                 } else {
>                     output.println(Text + "\t\tidentifier\n");
>                 }
>                 output.flush();
>
>                 // clear Text variable
>                 Text = "";
>                 break;
>
>             case 3:
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 if (isDigit(LF)) {
>                     Text += LF;
>                     LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 } else {
>                     state = 4;
>                 }
>                 break;
>             case 4:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tinteger");
>                 Text = "";
>                 break;
>             case 5:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tcomma\n");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 6:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tsemi-colon");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>
>             case 7:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tcolon");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>
>             case 8:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tquestion_mark");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 9:
>                 state = 0;
>                 output.println(Text + "\t\tleft_curly");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 10:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(Text + "\t\tright_curly");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 11:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(Text + "\t\tleft_parenth");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 12:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(Text + "\t\tright_parenth");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 13: // =, ==
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tassign_op") : Text + '=' + "\t\tequality_op");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 14: // +, +=, ++
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tarith_plus") : Text + '=' + "\t\tarith_assig_plus");
>                 Text = "";
>                 flag = 0;
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 if (LF == '+') {
>                     state = 19;
>                 }
>                 break;
>             case 15:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tarith_minus") : Text + '=' + "\t\tarith_assig_minus");
>                 flag = 0;
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             case 16:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tarith_mult") : Text + '=' + "\t\tarith_assig_mult");
>                 flag = 0;
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // / and =/
>             case 17:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tarith_div") : Text + '=' + "\t\tarith_assig_div");
>                 flag = 0;
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // % and %=
>             case 18:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tarith_modulus") : Text + '=' + "\t\tarith_assig_modulus");
>                 flag = 0;
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // ++ operator
>             case 19:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(Text + Text + "\t\tincrement_op");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // -- operator
>             case 20:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(Text + Text + "\t\tdecrement_op");
>                 Text = "";
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // < and <=
>             case 21:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tless_than_op") : Text + "\t\tless_or_equal_op");
>                 Text = "";
>                 flag = 0;
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>             // > and >=
>             case 22:
>                 state = 0;
>                 System.out.println(flag == 0 ? (Text + "\t\tgreater_than_op") : Text + '=' + "\t\tgreater_or_equal_op");
>                 Text = "";
>                 flag = 0;
>                 LF = text.charAt(position++);
>                 break;
>         }
>         System.out.flush();
>     }
> } }
> ```

- Thank you for helping me ^_^

Comment: Please indicate which lines are throwing your NPE (NullPointerException). The error message is telling you the line numbers, 27 and 78, and you'll want to indicate these lines to us with some obvious comments, i.e., `// ***** NPE HERE *****`

Comment: This question does not add value to the community. Try learning about debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Your offending line, 78:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
```

Which means that your input variable is null. Fix this -- initialize it to a valid Scanner object before using it, probably using your inputFile:

```
File inputFile = new File("D:\\input.txt");
if (!inputFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Input file, " + inputFile + ", does not exist.");
    System.exit(0);
}
input = new Scanner(input); // ****** add this ******
```

.

---

The key lesson from this is to read your exception messages critically for the usually tell you exactly what and where your problem is and then will allow you to fix it. For instance, your exception text mentioned,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at First_Project.First_Project.LetsDoThis(First_Project.java:78)
at First_Project.First_Project.main(First_Project.java:27)
```

which again should key you in on lines 78 and lines 27 of your First_Project.java file.